# Binding Bitmap in image view in listview of android

Tags: android, android-listview, bitmap, android-volley, picasso

I have **bitmap** and I already bind that in image view in list view, but issue is that it takes time to bind. Now I want to do lazy loading in that to reduce the time.

I have used **picasso and Volley** both in past where i have URL or URI of image but now i have bitmap with me to bind. So please suggest me some ideas or ways.
Any help will be appreciated

Comment: "Now I want to do lazy loading in that to reduce the time" -- what "time" are you referring to? If you have the `Bitmap`, applying that to the `ImageView` should take no meaningful time. Use Traceview to determine exactly where your time is being spent.

Comment: Actually am using CBL database and want to bind image from attachment of CBL document. i have around 700 images in list view and it take around 5 seconds to bind in listview

Comment: When i do same thing with URI (from sd-card)and use picasso it hardly take 2 seconds in binding.

Comment: "i have around 700 images in list view and it take around 5 seconds to bind in listview" -- unless your device is the size of a small building, you are not showing 700 rows at once. Again, please use Traceview and similar tools to determine exactly where you are spending your time.

Comment: @CommonsWare ok will try and let you know, actually am confused why same take 2 seconds when binding from URI. lets see . thanks